# Cisco software to virtualize network setups

Tags: cisco

I remember that Cisco has software that allows you create  virtual network setups, which is great for testing ideas and learning. However I can not remember the name of the software for life of me. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thanks in advance, and sorry for the my horrible memory :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the software you're looking for is [Packet Tracer](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/netacad/course_catalog/PacketTracer.html)

Comment: So do I. That is one wonderful program :)

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know packet tracer is just a network emulator and while its quite good for learning concepts if you want to virtualise a network you will need to use a program called GNS3 (www.gns3.net). This software creates Virtual Machines that actually run IOS images virtually so you will can see the realistic interaction between devices. Packet tracer is just an emulator but still works well for basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Check out cisco modelling labs, CML

http://www.mostlynetworks.com/2014/02/cisco-modeling-labs-overview/

this has the ability to plumb networks together out of virtual machines

There is also the cisco ONE-PK SDK that has IOSv within it as an example with I think a few sample virtual topologies